# Referencing a cell to have a line change

Tags: excel

In excel, it is possible to force a line change in the cell by pressing alt+enter when typing. Say I have cell A1 with "abc" on the top and "def" on the next line.

I want to write "=A1" in the cell A2 so that it displays the same thing. Unfortunately, they get concatenated, and in A2 it is simply written abcdef.

Does anyone know if it is even possible to do?

writing

```
="abc" & vbLF & "def"
```

does not work. Neither does chr(10). I can do it with vba but I would rather have a simple reference.

A copy/paste of A1 does not work either, as it splits the text between the cells underneath it. (A2 contains "abc", and A3 contains "def")

Comment: Seems to work as soon as I hit "Wrap text" in A2.. don't know if that is the full solution though...

Comment: My god you are right. I assumed they had been concatenated into a single word. Post as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select the cell with the formula and hit "Wrap Text" the line breaks will appear as they were in the referenced cell.

For those that don't know where wrap text is at it is under the "Home" Tab in the "Alignment" category: (for excel 2010)

[image]